# ASP.NET MVC Add Roles manually

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am really new to `ASP.NET` `MVC` programming and I am currently using the default template for a web application project that contains the methods for registering user, user management and so on including the `db` as well. However, is it possible for me to add `roles` manually in the default database as follows:

[image: Adding roles manually]

and get it working instead of using views to create `roles`?

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result?

Comment: I did but I can't really retrieve the roles using ``ASP.NET IDENTITY``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add role to a user you first need to add a new role in `AspNetRoles` table (which you already did)
Then you need to insert the corresponding user's id and role id into `AspNetUserRoles` table

Comment: Yeah, I did as well but how do I retrieve the role of the user logged in?
@Steve

Comment: @Pow4Pow5 ((RolePrincipal)User).GetRoles(); or Roles.GetRolesForUser()

Answer (score 0):

Identity 3 (ASP.NET Core)

Creating:

```
var role = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Admin");
if (role == null)
{
   role = new IdentityRole("Admin");
   await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
}
```

Btw: Best to place your roles into a constants class.

Retrieving role of user:
I used following extension method.

```
public static string GetUserRole(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    if (principal == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(principal));
    }
    return principal.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == "role")?.Value;
}
```

Controller:

```
var role = User.GetUserRole();
```